# Named route does not exist for name : SLIM FRAMEWORK 3

Tags: php, paypal, slim

Why i cant view the page when successful transaction in PayPal was done?

**routes.php**

```
$this->group('/paypal-transaction', function() {
     $this->get('', 'PortalPaypalTransactionController:show')->setName('portal.paypal_transaction');
});
```

and this is the code on my **controller**

```
$this->flash->addMessage('success', 'Load-up successful!');
    return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('portal/paypal-transaction'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the path for `portal/paypal-transaction` but you declared it as `portal.paypal_transaction`. So adjust one of it to match the other.

Comment: i've already change 

pathFor('portal/paypal-transaction') to  pathFor('portal.paypal-transaction')

but it loads too long and nothings happen

Comment: also changed the `_` to `-` or vice versa?

Comment: when i change the _ to - it gives an error message

"Named route does not exist for name"

Comment: the string in pathFor and setName should be the same, if that so and there is still an empty page, have a look at your php error log